# Pandas failing to seperate columns of csv-File

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am currently trying to extract data from a .csv-File using panda's read_csv-function. 
My .csv-File has the following format:

[Link to first image as I am not allowed to include images][1]

It seems to me like a reasonable format only the # in the header line troubles me a bit, but does not influence the problem I am facing.

When I read the file with `pandas.read_csv(csv_path)`, it puts all lines into the first column of the generated dataframe and assigns all other columns with NAN-values, even though it correctly assigns the header line. 
It seems to me as if it does not detect the separators and thus regards the whole line as just one big entry generating the following dataframe:
[Link to second image as I am not allowed to include images][2]

My current code:

```
import pandas

csv_path = 'sample.csv'
data_frame = pandas.read_csv(csv_path)
```

Comment: Do not use images. Copy and paste the sample csv file.

Comment: Please share the code and few lines of the csv file so that we can work on it.

Comment: @Dustrokes I included some lines and my code

Comment: @MelleBra I just tested your sample file and it works fine.

Comment: @Dustrokes Really? That's weird

Comment: @Dustrokes I am still getting the same picture as above...

Answer (score 0):

It is working as it should:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
print(pd.__version__)

s = '''#filename,file_size,file_attributes,region_count,region_id,region_shape_attributes,region_attributes
video_0029-frame_00000.jpeg,1092976,"{}",22,0,"{""name"":""rect"",""x"":68,""y"":283,""width"":58,""height"":20}","{""class"":""Car""}"
video_0029-frame_00000.jpeg,1092976,"{}",22,1,"{""name"":""rect"",""x"":676,""y"":297,""width"":52,""height"":19}","{""class"":""Car""}"
video_0029-frame_00000.jpeg,1092976,"{}",22,2,"{""name"":""rect"",""x"":708,""y"":254,""width"":55,""height"":20}","{""class"":""Car""}"'''

pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
```

out:

```
0.24.1

                     #filename  file_size file_attributes  region_count  \
0  video_0029-frame_00000.jpeg    1092976              {}            22   
1  video_0029-frame_00000.jpeg    1092976              {}            22   
2  video_0029-frame_00000.jpeg    1092976              {}            22   

   region_id                            region_shape_attributes  \
0          0  {"name":"rect","x":68,"y":283,"width":58,"heig...   
1          1  {"name":"rect","x":676,"y":297,"width":52,"hei...   
2          2  {"name":"rect","x":708,"y":254,"width":55,"hei...   

  region_attributes  
0   {"class":"Car"}  
1   {"class":"Car"}  
2   {"class":"Car"}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, your example works fine for me too. However, if I copy the data into a csv-File and try to read from the file pandas still puts the whole data into the first column.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try passing `quotechar` and `sep` arguments in Pandas.read_csv():

```
data_frame = pd.read_csv(csv_path, sep=',', quotechar ='"')
```

Running that, I got the following output when calling `data.head()`:

```
                      filename  file_size file_attributes  region_count  \
0  video_0029-frame_00000.jpeg    1092976              {}            22   
1  video_0029-frame_00000.jpeg    1092976              {}            22   
2  video_0029-frame_00000.jpeg    1092976              {}            22   

   region_id                            region_shape_attributes  \
0          0  {"name":"rect","x":68,"y":283,"width":58,"heig...   
1          1  {"name":"rect","x":676,"y":297,"width":52,"hei...   
2          2             {"name":"rect","x":708,"y":254,"width"   

  region_attributes  
0   {"class":"Car"}  
1   {"class":"Car"}  
2               NaN
```

Comment: Well, that didn't work for me either. I suspect that it is a version problem. Which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I'm using 0.23.4.  Python version 3.6.5.  Is that close to what you're on?  You can check with `print(pandas.__version__)` if you're using Python 3.x

Comment: Yeah somewhat, Python 3.7 and pandas 0.24.2. I will downgrade my pandas and report if anything changes

Comment: You could try that. Or, mess around with some of the parameters. You could also use the csv module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) from Python, then convert that to Pandas. Finally, check the encoding of your csv file.  Usually utf-8 is Windows standard, but yours might be something different.